# HLS problems in fire tv webapp

Tags: jquery, http-live-streaming, m3u8, amazon-fire-tv

I downloaded the web starter kit for amazon fire tv from here

https://github.com/amzn/web-app-starter-kit-for-fire-tv

and used the "simple-live" example app

I'm having trouble getting movies into HLS. gives me this error

> ErrorType : Video Playback Error ErrorMessage : Video source not
>   available or supported ErrorStack :
>   ErrorHandler/this.genStack@http://localhost:6881/js/error-handler.js:172:21
>   PlayerView/this.errorHandler<@http://localhost:6881/js/player-view.js:173:57

Timestamp : Fri Oct 18 2019 11:31:02 GMT+0200 (Ora legale dell’Europa centrale)

Movies in hls from our app work great

```
"media": [
      {
        "id": "live-id-1",
        "title": "test",
        "thumbURL": "assets/l11.jpg",
        "imgURL": "assets/nasa-logo.jpg",
        "videoURL": "/m3u8/xxxxx.m3u8",
        "type": "video-live",
        "alwaysLive": true,
        "description": "test"
      },
```

has anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm that your .m3u8 file points to the right video source.

Comment: Confirm...
it's the same one we use for other applications